# Laravel Eloquent: How to filter results of related models?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have tables on Database:

orders

```
 --id
  --customer_id
```

customers

```
  --id
  --name
  --country_id
```

countries

```
 --id
  --name
```

And next eloquent models:

Order.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
   /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function customer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer');
    }
}
```

Customer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Customer extends Model
{
   /**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
     */
    public function country()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Country');
    }
}
```

Country:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Country extends Model
{

}
```

Now i need to get all order where customer country name like 'Uk' by one sql query. How I can do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should do the trick:

```
Order::whereHas('customer.country', function($innerQuery) {
    $innerQuery->where('countries.name', 'LIKE', 'Uk');
})->get();
```

Comment: You don't need `countries.name`, `name` alone is enough. Actually I'm not even sure if it works at all with the table name prefixed to the column... And maybe use `%UK%` when using `like`.

Comment: "I'm not sure if it works ..." - It does; you can use the prefix or omit it. In some cases it's required due to ambiguity of column names, but most cases it's not.

Comment: Alright, makes sense. Especially with a column named `name`. :)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a good way of thinking but maybe I have helped

```
$orders = App\Order::whereHas('customer.country', function ($query) {
        $query->where('name', 'like', 'UK%');
    })->get();
```

Comment: `$query->country()->where()` doesn't look like the right syntax; I think you can just drop the `country()` and it should work. Although, `order` doesn't have a `country` relationship, so this would be an error.

Comment: You're right. But after minor corrections, the code should work.

Comment: Check [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).